# Proving $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am told that we can go about this inductively.

Let $P(n)$ be the statement: “$\mathbb{N}^n$ is countable” $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*Base Case:* $\mathbb{N}^1 = \mathbb{N}$ is countable by definition, so $\checkmark$

*Inductive Step:* $\mathbb{N}^{k+1}$ $“=”$ $\mathbb{N}^k \times \mathbb{N}$

We know that $(A,B)$ countable $\implies$ $A \times B$ is countable. I am stuck on the part where I have to prove the rest, but I know that, for example, $(1,2,7) \in \mathbb{N}^3 \notin \mathbb{N}^2 \times \mathbb{N}$ but instead $((1,2),7) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \times \mathbb{N}$. So how would I go about proving the statement.

Comment: -1: you asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/71850) two months ago...

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate, I think that the question here is essentially about the induction step. It is a valid question which I got asked plenty of times by my own students when asked about it.

Comment: @tb OP obviously knows that product of two countable sets is countable -it's mentioned in his attempted proof. From the formulation of the questions it seems to me, that his problem is to see that $\mathbb N^k\times\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^{k+1}$ is the same thing (as far as the cardinality is concerned.) I agree that the OP might have explained more clearly what he is asking, but I do not think that it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you want to prove something about cardinalities you actually say "I don't really care *who* is in the set, I just care about its size".

This means that you don't really care that $(1,2,3)\notin\mathbb N^2\times\mathbb N$, because once you proved that $\mathbb N^2\times\mathbb N$ is countable you have a natural bijection: $$\left(\left(x,y\right),z\right)\mapsto\left(x,y,z\right)$$
This function is clearly bijective, and while you cannot write "clearly" in a homework assignment - it is not hard to prove that for yourself as well. Every $(n+1)$-tuple is just an $n$-tuple with an additional element.

Alternatively, you can use the fact that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable as well and just "skip" the above part, by doing it implicitly as follows:

So now the induction step would be to take $f_n\colon\mathbb N^n\to\mathbb N$ which is a bijection, define $g\colon\mathbb N^{n+1}\to\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ as follows:

$$g((a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1})) = (f_n(a_1,\ldots,a_n),a_{n+1})$$

This function is injective since two different tuples will either have a different coordinate $k\le n$ in which case the $f_n$ part would be different by injectivity of $f_n$; or different coordinate at the $n+1$ place, in which case the right coordinate of the image will be different.

It is also surjective due to a similar argument. And then $f_{n+1}$ is the composition of $g$ with a fixed bijection from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: How would the function be surjective?

Comment: Is it slightly clearer now?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

It is enough to prove that $A \times B$ is countable whenever $A$ and $B$ are countable.  To do this, write

$$
A = \{a_0,a_1,a_2, \dots\}
$$
and
$$
B = \{b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots\}.
$$
To find a bijection, consider the map

$$\begin{align}
0 \mapsto (a_0,b_0)
\\
1 \mapsto (a_1,b_0)
\\
2 \mapsto (a_0,b_1)
\\
3 \mapsto (a_2,b_0)
\\
4 \mapsto (a_1,b_1)
\\
5 \mapsto (a_0,b_2)
\\
6 \mapsto (a_0,b_3)
\\
7 \mapsto (a_1,b_2)
\\
\vdots \qquad\quad
\end{align}$$
and show this map is a bijection.  This map is "natural" in the sense that if you draw out the set of ordered pairs of nonnegative integers, this map follows a logical path.  It is called the Cantor pairing function and it [can be described visually](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Pairing_natural.svg).

Now to see that the previous statement is enough to prove what you want, use induction.

Comment: Is this true if K is equal to infinity??????

Answer (score 2):

Define $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^k$ by just the inclusion into the first coordinate, this is clearly an injection. Define $g:\mathbb{N}^k\to\mathbb{N}:(a_1,\cdots,a_k)\mapsto p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ where $p_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ prime. This is an injection by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. The rest follows by the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: If $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$, as is usual in set theory, then your map $g$ is not injective, since you cannot tell if there are trailing $0$s on the sequence or not. You can fix this either by also encoding $k$ itself, or by adding $1$ to each exponent, or by including $p_{k+1}^1$ at the end as an end-marker or probably also in other ways.

Comment: @JDH I personally don't include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, and I think it's fairly clear that adding in $0$ doesn't really change the cardinality, so that there is really no need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  For your inductive step, you have assumed there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^k$ and $\mathbb{N}$.  You now want to prove that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^{k+1}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.  So if you use the bijection you have on the first $k$ components of $\mathbb{N}^{k+1}$ what do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:\mathbb{N^K}\to \mathbb{N^K\times \{m \}}$ defined by $$f(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_k)=(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_k,m)$$ is clearly a bijection for fixed $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and we can write $\mathbb{N^{K+1}}$ as $$\mathbb{N^{K+1}}=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\{\mathbb{N^K\times \{m \}}\}$$ and this being a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Is this true if K is equal to infinity??????

Comment: @sani No. In fact, the set of sequences with entries $o$ or $1$ is not countable.