# Is the set of polynomial with coefficients on $\mathbb{Q}$ enumerable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Using the definition of enumerability of sets:

A non-empty set B is enumerable iff there is a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\supset L \rightarrow B$.

So, I have to prove that the set of polynomial of one variable with coefficients on $\mathbb{Q}$ is enumerable. What I thought is that I can write every polynomial $p_0=A_0^0+A_1^0X+\dots +A_n^0X^n$ as

$$p_0=(A_0^0,A_1^0,\dots ,A_n^0,\dots ),$$

where the $A_i's$ are 0 except for a finite number of them.
To say that this set is enumerable is the same that to say (denoting this set by B):

$$B=\{p_1,p_2,\dots\}$$

Now define the polynomial

$$ p=(x_0 \neq A_0^0, x_1 \neq A_1^1, \dots), $$

where every $x_i \neq A_i^i$. This polynomial is obviously not in the list B.

My question is: **my approach is right to conclude that the set B is non-enumerable?**

Comment: Have you done the proof yet which shows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable (enumerable)? If yes, you can use that and some other theorem which says that a union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @Jeff Yes I have, but I don't see how the set B is the union of any other sets.

Comment: I think: If $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and $A_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $p_j$ is (not really) a union of $A_i$s (more like concatenatiing two sets), and $B$ is a concatenation of $p_i$s, then...  I guess this breaks down because concatenation isn't quite  a union. But still, it seems that if two countable $A$ and $B$ are made into a set of $(a \in A, b \in B)$, then the new set is countable, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First note that enumerable usually means can be *effectively* enumerated, where as you seem to ask if it is *countable* (or denumerable).

The conclusion is wrong, so the approach cannot be right. The set *is* countable. As for the approach, note that you are defining a polynomial with infinitely many non-zero coefficients, which is therefore not a polynomial.

Otherwise the argument would be reduced to an even worse state: a misinterpretation of the Cantor diagonal argument. That is, you are listing the polynomials and then finding something not on that concrete list; whereas the actual argument is "given any enumeration, we can find something not on the list".

To see that the polynomials are countable first note that $\mathbb Q$ is countable. This means that if we show that polynomials whose coefficients are in $\mathbb N$ give a countable set, we can use the bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$ to prove that the polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ are countable.

Now to see that, first we can (as you did) identify the polynomial with finite sequences, then we can find explicit bijections between $\mathbb N$ and the set of finite sequences, for example:

$$\langle a_0,\ldots,a_n\rangle\mapsto p_0^{a_0}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{a_n}-1$$

Where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number.

---

Of course that if you are allowed to rely on the fact that countable unions of countable sets are countable, you can take the approach which avoids the explicit bijection:

- $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable;
- By induction if $\mathbb N^k$ is countable then $\mathbb N^{k+1}$ is countable.

The set of all finite sequences is equal to $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb N^n$, and therefore is a countable union of countable sets.

**Further reading:**

1. [The cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable/54159#54159)
2. [Cartesian Product of Two Countable Sets is Countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71850/countable-sets-and-the-cartesian-product-of-them/72027#72027)
3. [Proving $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91665/proving-mathbbnk-is-countable/91697#91697)

Comment: Thank you, now I see what is wrong in my argument, and your hints are really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

No, because in fact $B$ **is** enumerable.

Your argument fails because each $p_k$ has only finitely many non-zero coefficients. It turns out that the ‘polynomial’ that you construct by this diagonal argument isn’t actually a polynomial at all, but an infinite series: it has infinitely many non-zero coefficients.

Since $B$ is enumerable, you should instead be looking for a proof of this. One approach is to divide $B$ up into more manageable pieces: for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $B_n$ be the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$. Presumably you already know that $\Bbb Q$ is enumerable, so it’s easy to see that $B_0$ is enumerable. Can you see how to find a bijection between $\Bbb{Q}^{n+1}$ and $B_n$?

Comment: Yes, now that I stop to think, there couldn't be a polynomial like that.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott : I see your point but it is much more than $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$ is the finite union of all $\mathbb{Q}^i$, where eventhough $i < \infty$, $i$ can be as large as I want. What is the largest $i$? this confuses me. It is as if $i$ can go all the way to $\infty$ and then the Cantor diagonal argument will apply, We can make a bijection with the set $[0,1]$.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: There is no largest $i$. One first proves that $B_n$ is countable for each $n\ge 0$. One way to do this is to find a bijection between $B_n$ and $\Bbb Q^{n+1}$ and to show that $\Bbb Q^n$ is countable for each $n\ge 0$, if one has not already done so. Then $B=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}B_n$ is the union of countably many countable sets, and therefore it is countable. There is no place in this argument where anything like the diagonal argument is even possible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott :  Here is the place for it. Pick $B_n=(x_1, x_2, x_n, 0, 0. \cdots)$ where $x_i$ is either 1 or 0. Think about the binary representation of a number $b=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i/2^i$. For $n$ large enough, we can fit this number to any number in the interval $[0,1]$ using the binary representation of the number...well maybe not. We need $n$ to include $\infty$.  Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: There is no problem there, and no opportunity to use the diagonal argument, for the simple reason that $\Bbb Q$ is provably countable. If you try to diagonalize an enumeration of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$, you end up producing an irrational number, not a rational that you failed to enumerate.