# Is the set of integer coefficient polynomials countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials, cardinals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the set of polynomial with coefficients on $\mathbb{Q}$ enumerable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118518/is-the-set-of-polynomial-with-coefficients-on-mathbbq-enumerable)

The set of integer coefficient polynomials are countable, when the cardinality of each set of  length n polynomial is intepreted as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some finite n, then union of countable sets is countable.

**What about this method, what is wrong with this ?**

Suppose $P(x)=a_{0} + a_1{x} + a_2 x^2+..........$ is an infinite length polynomial, for each coefficient $a_i$ we have $\mathbb{Z}$ possible choices, so for $\mathbb{Z}$ terms we may choose $|\mathbb{Z}|^\mathbb{Z}$ possible polynomials and since $|\mathbb{Z}|^\mathbb{Z} > 2^\mathbb{Z}$ the set of integer coefficient polynomials is uncountable.

Comment: There is a lovely bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}[X]$, namely, $\sum a_n x^n \rightarrow \prod p_n^{a_n}$ where $p_n$ is the nth prime. Of course, it is trivial to extend to $\mathbb{Z}$. As it was pointed out, polynomials are finite.

Comment: An integral polynomial gives a function from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. A power series doesn't. A polynomial is a finitely generated algebra over the co-efficient ring a power series is not.

Comment: @s.b. Being pedantic, but "a polynomial" is not "a finitely generated algebra." The "set of polynomials" is "a finitely generated algebra."

Comment: This is not an *exact* duplicate per se, but I think it is close enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would consider this an abstract duplicate since $|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{Q}|$ (but I can't vote...)

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, Yes I meant the polynomial algebra not a single polynomial per se.

Answer (score 3):

An 'infinite length polynomial' is not a polynomial, it is a (formal) power series.

**Edit:** Also $\left| \mathbb{Z} \right|^{\left| \mathbb{Z} \right|} = 2^{\left| \mathbb{Z} \right|}$, not $>$.

Comment: can you refer to some source please

Comment: @mehdi: Any textbook, or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) or [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/BasicPolynomial.html) or [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/polynomial.html) or etc.

Comment: In particular, we often say the fundamential theorem of algebra is that any non-constant polynomial has a complex root.  The inifinite power series, $1+x+x^2+... = \frac{1}{1-x}$ has not roots.