# Does an infinite polynomial define algebraic numbers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

As the title says, does a polynomial with an  infinite number of terms define algebraic numbers as roots? An algebraic number is defined as a solution to a polynomial with rational coefficients, but it is not usually specified whether this polynomial can have infinite terms.

Comment: It doesn't exist a polynomial "with infinite number of terms" (meaning, infinite number of non zero coefficients). That thing's called a power series and it is a rather different animal from polynomials.

Comment: An easy example is the “polynomial” $-1+\sum_{k\ge1}x^k$ which vanishes for $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In view of the wording at the end of the question, it seems worthwhile to say explicitly that neither infinitely many terms nor infinite terms are possible in a polynomial.

With infinitely many terms, you'd get power series (not polynomials), and these can have roots that are not algebraic; for example, $\pi$ is a root of the sine function, which is given by an everywhere convergent power series.

As for infinite terms, I don't know what that would mean.

Comment: It may be of interest to point out that every complex number is a root of some power series with **rational coefficients**. This was proved by Adolf Hurwitz in 1891. For more about this topic see my [18 December 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5441610) archived at Math Forum.

Answer (score 7):

No, by definition a polynomial has finitely many terms, despite the fact that polynomials of every finite degree exist.

Anyway, the algebraic numbers are dense in $\mathbb{C}$ and so any continuous function that is zero at all algebraic numbers is actually just zero.