# Algebraic numbers are countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Basically this question has many solutions in MSE for example [proof 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489186/prove-that-the-set-of-all-algebraic-numbers-is-countable), [proof 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50655/proving-the-countability-of-algebraic-numbers?rq=1) etc. I have also tried to prove it and wanted to checked. It is as follows:

1. My first claim is there are only countably many polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, i.e the set $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is countable. Which is probably easy to see as we can see it as $\mathbb{Z}^n$.
2. Since each polynomials has at most finite roots so if we consider all the roots in a set that will be nothing but countable union of finite sets, which is countable.

Hence, set of algebraic numbers are countable.

Comment: We can see $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ needs to be thought again. What is $n$?

Comment: `easy to see as we can see it as Z^n` Not obvious what you mean by that (what's $n$?). See however [Prove that the set of integer coefficients polynomials is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341349/prove-that-the-set-of-integer-coefficients-polynomials-is-countable). Then step 2 is the easy part.

Comment: You can view $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as $\bigcup_{n\geq 0}\mathbb{Z}^n$, but not as you claim.

Comment: Okay thanks, now I got it. $n$ to be chosen. It's not obvious.

Comment: Essentially right - but the set of polynomials is the union of the set of polynomials of each degree. Each of those sets is countable and a countable union of countable sets is countable.