# Inductive Proof of a countable set Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91665/proving-mathbbnk-is-countable)

I would like to prove that if S is countable then for any positive integer n the set $S^n$ (the n-fold Cartesian product of S with itself) is countable using mathematical induction.

I think I should initialize it at n=0 but I don't know where to go from there.

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: The result is trivial for $n=0$ and $n=1$, so your first step should be to prove it for $n=2$. Then you can use that result in your induction step to go from countability of $S^n$ to countability of $S^{n+1}$, since $S^{n+1}$ clearly admits a bijection with $S^n\times S$, a product of two countable sets.

Comment: Thanks Brian. How do you prove the countability of a cartesian product of two countable sets ?

Comment: There are many ways; one is discussed in considerable detail [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Comment: I made it with your help. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brian gave me some excellent advise and I found a way to do it.
Showing that the cartesian $S^n \times S$