# I need help with proofs pertaining to countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Countable Sets and the Cartesian Product of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71850/countable-sets-and-the-cartesian-product-of-them)
>   [Inductive Proof of a countable set Cartesian product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139673/inductive-proof-of-a-countable-set-cartesian-product)

Let $A$ and $B$ be countable sets.

(a) Show that $A \times B$ is countable. Hint: Show that there is a bijection from $A\times  B$ onto a subset of $\Bbb Z \times\Bbb Z$:

(b) Use induction on $n$ to show that $A_1 \times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n$ is countable if $A_1, A_2,\ldots, A_n$ are countable.

Comment: Have you tried searching the site?

Comment: Was the hint not helpful enough?

Comment: Note, though that the proofs in the answers to the question that @Amr mentions are very different from the one suggested in your hint. They are direct proofs; yours makes use of the result that $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is countable, which presumably you’ve already proved.

Comment: Note that the question found by @Asaf covers only (b).

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, luckily Amr's duplicate covers (a).

Comment: @Asaf: But not in a way compatible with the hint in the problem, which is why I won’t vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

A small additional nudge for (a): if $f:W\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ are injections, the map

$$W\times X\to Y\times Z:\langle w,x\rangle\mapsto\big\langle f(w),g(x)\big\rangle$$

is an injection. Why, and how is this useful for your problem?

There really isn’t much to say about (b) that isn’t already present in *Use induction*. Note, though, that you can work on (b) even without having done (a). The proof of (b) does not require that you know how to prove (a): it requires only that you assume (a) to be true.