# If two sets are countable and infinite show the Cartesian product is countable.

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

If I have two sets say A and B which are countable and infinite then how would I show that the Cartesian product is countable.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Have you seen proof that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable?

Comment: The easiest way to show something is countable is to create a bijection between the two sets.

Comment: How would I create this bijection. Would I need to show its both surjective and injective.

Comment: You could have a look at the related questions on the right. Like this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71850/cartesian-product-of-two-countable-sets-is-countable.

Comment: This is an extremely famous problem and given that you have not explained anything about how you have worked on it, we can't do anything that a Google search can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set  of natural numbers is the prototype for countable sets; anything in bijective correspondence with this set, by definition, is a countable set.

Let us see the natural numbers in their physical/visual form. We write them out in base 10. Then we get all possible finite sequences formed by the symbols $0,1,2,\ldots,9$ (avoiding 0 at the starting position).

As numbers can be written uniquely in any basis (binary system, decimal system) it follows that *given a finite set of symbols, the collection of strings of all possible finite length composed of these symbols* is a countable set.

Now let us take a visual description of the cartesian product: a typical element looks like $(13374,26905)$. We can see that physically these are subset of all possible strings of finite length composed of the *thirteen* symbols: the decimal digits, opening and closing parentheses, the comma.

So this is a subset of the  countable set of all strings of finite length formed with 13 symbols, hence countable.

Note that this actually  proves  that product of three (or any finite number of) countable sets is  also countable.

BONUS: To prove countability of rationals look at their physical forms, other than the minus sign, the slash sign for division should be enlisted, and same argument will work.