# The cartesian product of a finite amount of countable sets is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

I want to prove that the cartesian product of a finite amount of countable sets is countable. I can use that the union of countable sets is countable.

**My attempt:**

Let $A_1,A_2, \dots, A_n$ be countable sets.

We prove the statement by induction on $n$

For $n = 1$, the statement clearly holds, as $A_1$ is countable. Now, suppose that $B := A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots A_{n-1}$ is countable.

We have: $$B \times A_n = \{(b,a)|b \in B, a \in A_n\}$$
$$= \bigcup_{a \in A_n} \{(b,a)|b \in B\}$$

and $\{(b,a)|b \in B\}$ is countable for a fixed $a \in A_n$, since the function $f_a: B \to B \times \{a\}: b \to (b,a)$ is a bijection, and $B$ is countable by induction hypothesis. Because the union of countable sets remains countable, we have proven that $(A_1 \times \dots A_{n-1}) \times A_n$ is countable, and because $f: (A_1 \times \dots A_{n-1}) \times B \to A_1 \times \dots A_{n-1} \times A_n: ((a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}),a_n) \mapsto (a_1, \dots, a_{n-1},a_n)$
is a bijection, the result follows.

Questions:

> - Is this proof correct/rigorous?
> - Are there other proofs that are
>     easier?
> - Someone pointed out that we can prove this theorem using the
>     'zigzag'-argument. Can someone provide this proof? I think this
>     zigzag-method is too graphical, and therefore not rigorous, so if
>     someone can clarify why this method is completely rigorous, I would be
>     more than glad to award him the bonus.

Comment: I'm asking whether this is correct, not an alternative method

Comment: Yes it is correct. But do you know the proof that countable Union of countable sets is countable?

Comment: Yes, and that one uses the diagonal argument (I'm working through Rudin's book, where it is proven). I find the diagonal argument somewhat unrigorous, that's why I want to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: you avoid a particular technique, but use a result proven by that technique... btw. that result need countable choice, which is stronger than what you want to prove.

Comment: @user251257 Isn't the 'diagonal argument' the technique Cantor used to prove the *un*-countability of sets? I am familiar with the 'zig-zag' method to enumerate all elements of an infinite 2D array ... is that what you mean?  If so, I have never seen that referred to as the 'diagonal argument' ... or did I miss something?  IT *should* have a name though ....

Comment: @Bram28 yes i meant that. Sorry for using the wrong term.

Comment: @user251257  No problem! There really should be a name for that method!  I always refer to it as the zig-zag method in the absence of a better name ..:)

Comment: Perhaps you could comment on what you are expecting in order to reward the bounty. Your argument is correct. And for proving that a product of countable sets is countable, the zig-zag argument on which that proof is based is correct and rigorous. What further are you asking? For example, are you asking for further explanation why the zig-zag argument is rigorous?

Comment: Will edit my question. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: In German, the argument involved in showing that $\mathbb Q$ is countable is referred to as Cantor's first diagonal argument, the uncountability of $\mathbb R$ is proved using Cantor's second diagonal argument. I don't know whether this goes back to Cantor though, and why this didn't make its way into English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase 'the union of countable sets is countable' is wrong unless you add the word 'countable' before 'union'.

The zig-zag argument is nothing but a graphical way to describe a bijection  between  $ {\Bbb N}\times{\Bbb N}$ and  $ {\Bbb N}$.
You may also give an explicit formula for such a bijection. Using the French notation that $0\in {\Bbb N}$,
 you may check that

$$ \phi (m,n) = m + \sum_{k=1}^{m+n} k $$
yields such a bijection. The inverse map is the 'zig-zag' path. Having constructed this function we may iterate to solve when taking further products. For example:
  $$ (m,n,p) \in  {\Bbb N}\times{\Bbb N} \times {\Bbb N}\mapsto \phi(\phi(m,n),p) \in {\Bbb N} $$
is a bijection etc...

Update: Some hints for the bijection:

1) Injectivity: Show that if $(m,n) \neq (m',n') \in {\Bbb N} \times {\Bbb N}$ then $$m + \sum_{k=1}^{m+n} k \neq m' + \sum_{k=1}^{m'+n'} k$$
(distinguish the cases when $m+n=m'+n'$ and  $m+n \neq m'+n'$)

2) Surjectivity: We have $\phi(0,0)=0$. Suppose $\phi(m,n)=j$. Then if $n>0$ note that $\phi(m+1,n-1)=j+1$, while if $n=0$ then $\phi(0,m+1)=j+1$. Conclude using induction ...

Comment: If you can elaborate why this graphical method is rigirous, I will award you the bounty.

Comment: You (just) need to show that $\phi$ is a bijection. You may do that by induction. That is the proof. The zig-zag path is just an interpretation: Try to write down at each couple $(m,n) \in {\Bbb N}^2$ the value of $\phi(m,n)$. Connecting them in increasing order yields the path.

Comment: What would the formula for the inverse map look like? Does it exist in "closed form"? I'm struggling to see how, given a natural number $l$, I can achieve the $l = m + \sum_{k=1}^{m+n} k$ decomposition (and further, that this decomposition is unique), so that I can obtain $(m,n)$ given $l$. Would it be possible to comment on that?

Comment: @EE18 Well, if you call $N=n+m$ then you want to solve  $\ell = \phi(m,n)=m+N(N+1)/2$ with $N$ being an integer and $0\leq m\leq N$. Then $N$ is the largest integer for which $N(N+1)/2\leq \ell$ which leads to the closed formulae $N=\lfloor \sqrt{2\ell+1/4} -1/2 \rfloor$, $m=\ell-N(N+1)/2$ and $n=N-m$ but this probably doesn't help on anyone's intuition. But you may in fact program it and see it works (I just did so).
To gain intuition I think it is better simply to calculate $\phi(m,n)$ for small values of $m,n$ and plot the values in a coordinate system. Then the zig-zag curve appears.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer Prof. Rugh. My number theory is rather weak, so I didn't follow some of the inferences you made on the way through, but your point at the end re: what actually helps intuition is well taken. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For countable $A_1,...,A_m$ form their cartesian product $A_1 \times ... \times A_m=\{(a_1,...,a_m) ; a_1 \in A_1,...,a_m \in A_m\}$.

This cartesian product can be written as $\bigcup_{j_1=1}^{w_1}... \bigcup_{j_m=1}^{w_m} \{(a_{j_1 1}...a_{j_m m} )\}$ where $w_k$ is either finite or equal to $\infty$ for $k=1,...,m$.

Since we have finite number of unions and every of them is at most countable then cartesian product is also countable.

Comment: Your proof is what I made rigorous with the induction argument, it seems.

Comment: @Math_QED But I do not use induction as you see and this proof looks simple. You wanted some other proofs, right?

Comment: Yes, but this is essentially the same proof, just not with induction. Thanks for the answer though (+1)

Comment: @Math_QED For me, it is not essentially the same, whether there is induction or there is no induction is logically very different matter.

Comment: I can argue that the use of $...$ is not rigorous. To make it rigorous, you would have to use an induction argument anyway.

Comment: @Math_QED I can argue that $...$ is obvious from definition. :) :)