# Why is the proof of "countable many product of countable sets is countable" wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, infinite-product

As [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500849/infinite-cartesian-product-of-countable-sets-is-uncountable) clearly shows that the countable many product of countable sets is uncountable. However, I do not understand why the below proof is wrong:

### (False) Proof:

Let $A$ be a countable set. We use induction to show that the countably many product of $A$ with itself is countable. We use induction. When $n=1$, the theorem is true by our hypothesis.Let assume it is true for $A^n = A\times ... A : n$ times.

Since $A^{n+1} = A^n \times A$, which is the finite product of countable sets, it is also countable by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357899/the-cartesian-product-of-a-finite-amount-of-countable-sets-is-countable). Hence, by induction $A^n$ is countable for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. QED

### Question:

Why is the above proof wrong ? Where is the flaw ?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to show that $A^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ is countable.

Comment: To assert that every finite product of countable sets is countable implies that an infinite product of countable sets is countable is a *non sequitur*.

Comment: To put it another way, there is an important distinction to be drawn between arbitrarily large (but finite) $n$ and infinitely large $n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I used induction. Isn't that a valid move ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas You successfully proved that $A^n$ is countable for any $n\in\Bbb N$. Well done! But your "proof" does not even **consider** infinite products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof you give proves that $A^n$ is countable for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ however what you wish to prove is $A^\omega$ is countable. That is the propitiation is true for the infinite case. However $\omega$ isn't in $\mathbb{N}$ so the induction you use doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not trying to show that the uncountable product of countable sets is countable. I just want to show that **countable** product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: i.e $A^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ is countable.

Comment: @onurcanbektas $|\Bbb N|\notin\Bbb N$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I did not know that. Thanks

Comment: is $\omega = |\mathbb{N}|$ by the way ?

Comment: $ |\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0 = \omega $

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown By the way, that comment of yours cleared heck a lot of things in my mind. Thanks a lot again.