# Why is the union of countable many countable sets countable, but not the cross product?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Why is the union of countable many countable sets countable, but not the cross product?

Because, can't the cross product be written in the union format, something like:

Let 
$$A={E_1, E_2, ...} $$ 
Where each $E$ is a countable set, then isn't 
$$\prod _{i\in N}E_i=\cup_{j_1\in E_1}...\cup_{j_n\in E_n}...(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, ...)$$
Which would be countable?

Comment: Minor nitpick, I think the term you're looking for is the Cartesian product. The cross product is an operation on a pair of vectors.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Sometimes the Cartesian product called the cross product. (see e.g. [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CartesianProduct.html))

Comment: Huh, I wasn't aware. My bad, and thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might think of the example where each of the sets $E_i$ is the finite set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.  Then $\prod E_i$ can be seen as the set of all possible sequences of decimal digits.  If you put a decimal point in front, you have the set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$.  And hopefully you know Cantor's diagonalization argument which shows that is an uncountable set.

As a *very* rough explanation of the difference between union and product, union is like adding and product is like multiplying.  For instance, if $A,B$ are two disjoint finite sets with 100 elements each, then $A \cup B$ has 200 elements, but $A \times B$ has 10000.  You can see how repeated multiplication gives you much bigger numbers much faster than repeated addition - exponential growth is much faster than linear growth.  So it isn't surprising that taking products of sets could give you much bigger sets than unions would.

Comment: So is it not the case that the Cartesian product can be constructed out of Unions?

Comment: The specific answer I came across that used this is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439186/626797

Comment: @JacFrall: I do not know what you mean when you say "constructed out of".  You have to be more precise.

Comment: @JacFrall: The argument in that post is only valid when you take the Cartesian product of *finitely many* countable sets.  It breaks down completely when you take the product of *infinitely many* sets.

Comment: That is what was not making sense to me. Thank you