# Does there exist an injection $\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{ Z} \times \mathbb{ Q}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm thinking since $|\mathbb{R}|>|\mathbb{N}| \times| \mathbb{ Z} |\times |\mathbb{ Q}|$ then there can't be an injection, but is that true?

Comment: Yes, there cannot be such an injection.

Comment: Yes, of course uncountable sets can't inject into countable sets.

Comment: Look for Bernstein-Schroder theorem!

Comment: @HelloDarkness Although learning the Schröder-Bernstein theorem is a good idea in general, I don't see that it has much to do with this question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I guess, just thought of it because it lets me lsee injections as a "$\leq$" in cadnilaty, which, in this case, we know it be false.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2357899/631742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $N:=\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Q}$. Assume there exists such an injection $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow N$. Then the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow f(\mathbb{R}), g(x)=f(x)$ is a bijection (check this). As $N$ is countable (as it is the cartesian product of finitely many countable sets) and $g$ is a bijection, we would get that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable as well, which gives the desired contradiction.