# Help with proving $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}^{2}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Recently, in an answer to a question I posted on this website, I've been advised to use $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}^{2}$. The problem is I haven't been able to prove it, as I've only been able to find injective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^{2}$ and have been struggling with finding a bijective one. 
Any help with the proof will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a general note:  to prove that two sets have the same cardinality, it is generally easier to exhibit two injections (one from $A\to B$, the other from $B\to A$).  Explicit bijections are sometimes hard to write down (though the duplicate gives a typical bijection in this particular case).

Comment: It seems strange to mark as a duplicate of a closed question.

Comment: @SuzuHirose  I agree, but (among other good answers) it contained an explicit bijection, which I thought the OP might want, and of course it contained links to other duplicates.  I've noticed that some people seem to be able to closed a duplicate question while pointing to multiple duplicates (in the Closure notice I mean, not in the comments).  I don't know how to do that, nor do I know if that is something every user can do.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357899/the-cartesian-product-of-a-finite-amount-of-countable-sets-is-countable) is another duplicate, but I think the answers for the prior one are more informative.